# Is it possible to use OBIEE's Client tools for OAS and vice versa?

Tags: oracle, obiee, bi-tool

We have recently installed OAS on our test server. Our production on the other hand currently runs OBIEE 12.2.1.4. Both of them rely on the same database and connections are same.

I have uploaded an rpd file that is being used in OBIEE 12 into OAS. No errors were thrown during upload. Then I logged in OAS and tried to create a simple analysis. However when I click on `Create ->> Analysis` I don't see any subject areas. Here is an image:
[image]

In DV, attempted to create a simple data set from local subject area, got the following error:

> Cause: {1} Action: Invalid connection details.

[image]

I have checked the connection details in rpd, importing metada using existing connection is working fine. Has anyone face similar issue?

The only thing left to check is client developer tools for OBIEE and OAS. I haven't installed OAS client tools yet, since I already have clients tools for OBIEE and I believed OBIEE's developer tools would work with OAS, but it seems it won't. Also I am not sure if I install OAS tools , would they work with OBIEE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The versions of Admin Tool and the analytics application have to be aligned. Use wrong versions and risk messing up your system. Simple as that.

Comment: Thanks, Chris, I see. I've already downloaded OAS client tools and started installtion process. I'll post again if uploading from OAS admin tool solves the issue

Comment: Unfortunately, using Model Administration Tool for OAS and uploading rpd from there did not help. Still I am getting invalid connection details error